# Question about my proof of: $ \lim_{h \to 0}f(ch)=\lim_{ch \to 0}f(ch)$ for $c\neq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, logic, first-order-logic

This post will be broken up into two sections: the first section will contain the proof, and the second section will contain the question. The proof will be written formally, as the question is more easily understood referencing the formal description. (Note, the context of this post is in Spivak's *Calculus*, which treats all functions, unless otherwise stated, as having a domain of $\mathbb R$).

---

Prove: $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0}f(ch)=\displaystyle \lim_{ch \to 0}f(ch)$ for $c\neq 0$, which is equivalent to:

> If $c\neq 0$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0}f(ch)=L$, then $\displaystyle \lim_{ch \to 0}f(ch)=L$ $\quad$ and $\quad$ If $c\neq 0$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{ch \to 0}f(ch)=L$, then $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0}f(ch)=L$

We will only prove the first implication (the converse is completed similarly):

By assumption: $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0}f(ch)=L \iff \forall \varepsilon \gt 0 \ \exists \delta \gt 0 \  \forall h \in \mathbb R \left [ 0 \lt |h| \lt \delta \rightarrow |f(ch)-L| \lt \varepsilon \right ]$

We want to show that for an arbitrary $\varepsilon$, we can construct a $\delta$ such that $\color{red}{\forall ch} \in \mathbb R \left [ 0 \lt |ch| \lt \delta \rightarrow |f(ch)-L| \lt \varepsilon \right]$

For $\varepsilon$, we know by assumption that there is a $\delta_{\varepsilon}$ such that:

$\forall h \in \mathbb R \left [ 0 \lt |h| \lt \delta_{\varepsilon} \rightarrow |f(ch)-L| \lt \varepsilon \right ]$

Now, consider a $\delta ^* = \min\left(\delta_{\varepsilon},\frac{\delta_{\varepsilon}}{|c|}\right)$.

If $0 \lt |h| \lt \delta^* \leq \delta_{\varepsilon}$, by assumption we have: $|f(ch)-L| \lt \varepsilon$.

Further, if $0 \lt |h| \lt \delta^* \leq \frac{\delta_{\varepsilon}}{|c|}$, then $0 \lt |ch| \lt |c|\delta^*$.

Therefore, let our desired $\delta$ be defined as $\delta = |c|\delta^*$. As long as $0\lt|ch| \lt \delta$, all of our criteria is met.

---

In the above proof, I made use of the following statement:

$\color{red}{\forall ch} \in \mathbb R \left [ 0 \lt |ch| \lt \delta \rightarrow |f(ch)-L| \lt \varepsilon \right]$

Through my brief experience in maths, the *universally quantified* object $ch$ is atypical. I suspect the proper way to denote this is by establishing a function of the form: $g(h)=ch$ and then defining a single symbol as representing its output. i.e. something like $s_h :=g(h)$. More specifically, we should write $g$ formally as: $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ where $h \mapsto ch$.

We would then rewrite the statement as:

$\color{red}{\forall s_h} \in \mathbb R \left [ 0 \lt |s_h| \lt \delta \rightarrow |f(s_h)-L| \lt \varepsilon \right]$

This *seems* to emulate the more familiar notation of a universal quantifier, where only one symbol follows the quantifier.

I do not really know the deep theory behind first-order logic, but I suspect the reason this proof "works out" is because my new symbol $s_h$ has the capacity of sweeping through all objects within $\mathbb R$. Said differently, the previously defined function $g$ can be shown to be surjective with respect to $\mathbb R$.

**If the above is true, are there times where the change of variable function is not surjective, and this causes the equality between two limits to fail**?

Comment: $\lim_{h \to 0}f(1/h)\overset?= \lim_{1/h \to 0}f(1/h)$ seems wrong since the LHS limit is $f(\infty)$ while the RHS one is $f(0)$.

Comment: @VIVID yeah, I was trying to emphasize the function $g$ between $h$ and $1/h$...so as to interrogate the question of whether or not surjectivity is important. Any suggestions for a *better* example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **If** we have $$\lim\limits_{x \to x_0} f(x) = \ell$$ for some $\ell \in \mathbb R$ (i.e. exists), and **if** $\varphi$ is a function such that $$\lim\limits_{t \to t_0} \varphi(t) = x_0$$ for some $t_0 \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm \infty\}$, **and** $\varphi(t) \ne x_0 $ when $t$ is in some deleted nbhd of $t_0$, **then** $$\lim\limits_{t\to t_0} f(\varphi(t)) = \ell$$ that is $$\lim\limits_{x \to x_0} f(x) = \lim\limits_{t\to t_0} f(\varphi(t))$$

- In your example, $\varphi(t) = ct$ works since if $$\lim\limits_{h \to h_0} f(ch) = \ell$$ exists, then we can take $t_0 = h_0/c$ (legal because $c \ne 0)$ so that $$\lim\limits_{t \to t_0} \varphi(t) = \lim\limits_{t \to h_0/c}(ct) = c \cdot \dfrac{h_0}{c} = h_0$$
- For counter-example, we should think of any example that at least one of those conditions is not satisfied. Think of $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} x$$ (where $f(x) = x$ and $x_0 = 0$) for simplicity. Then, if we take $\varphi(t) = t^2+1$, for example, we **cannot** find $t_0 \in \mathbb R \cup \{\pm\infty\}$ such that $$\lim\limits_{t\to t_0} \varphi(t) = 0$$ (which is our $x_0$) since $\varphi(t) \ge 1$ for any $t \in \mathbb R$ and also $$\lim\limits_{t \to \pm\infty} \varphi(t) = +\infty \ne 0$$
  Note that, **however**, $\varphi(t) = 1/t$ would work since we can take $t_0 = \infty$ so that $$\lim\limits_{t \to t_0} \varphi(t) = 0 = x_0$$ and
  $$\begin{array}{c|c}
  \varphi : & \begin{matrix}\mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R \\ t \longmapsto \dfrac{1}{t}\end{matrix}
  \end{array}$$
  is **not** surjective.

---

**EDIT:** I thought you were mainly asking for change of variables inside limits and the importance of surjectivity in the substitution.

According to reasonable comments, let's prove the following with the abovementioned arguments and the definition of limits:
$$\color{navy}{\lim_{h \to 0}f(ch)}= \ell \iff \color{fuchsia}{\lim_{ch \to 0}f(ch)} = \ell \tag{$c \ne 0$}$$
$(\Leftarrow)$ In the second limit, take $\varphi(t) = t/c$. Then ($t \leftrightarrow h$)
$$\color{fuchsia}{\lim_{h \to 0} f(h)} = \ell$$
which means for any $\varepsilon > 0$ we have
$$|f(h) - \ell| < \varepsilon \tag{$\star$}$$
whenever $|h| < \color{fuchsia}\delta$ for some $\color{fuchsia}\delta = \color{fuchsia}\delta(\varepsilon) > 0$. Then we can take $\color{navy}{\delta'} = \color{fuchsia}\delta/|c|$ so that $(\star)$ would imply
$$|f(ch) - \ell| < \varepsilon$$
whenever $|h| < \color{navy}{\delta'} = \color{fuchsia}\delta/|c|$ since $|ch| < |c|\color{navy}{\delta'} = \color{fuchsia}\delta$. So, we have
$$\lim_{h \to 0}f(ch) = \ell$$ The converse is similar.

Comment: Just what I wanted! Could you please clarify what the motivation behind this requirement is: "... **and** $\varphi(t) \ne x_0 $ when $t$ is in some nbhd of $t_0$..."? Also, by "in some neighborhood of $t_0$", does that *include* $t_0$ itself? When I see "neighborhood", I usually think of $(t_0-\delta, t_0+\delta)$, which *would* include $t_0$.

Comment: The confusion with my last point is that $\varphi(t_0)=h_0$...which seems to violate your 3rd condition. Perhaps I am misunderstanding. Is the third statement meant to be interpreted as: $\exists \delta \gt 0 \text{ s.t. } \forall t \in (t_0-\delta,t_0+\delta) \setminus \{t_0\} \left [ \varphi(t) \neq x_0 \right]$...emphasis on that $...\setminus \{t_0\}...$ tidbit.

Comment: @S.Cramer Yes, you were right. I had to say "in some *deleted nbhd of $t_0$*". The motivation behind that requirement (which is in your first comment) is that it allows you to find the limit even if functions are not defined there. For example, think of $\sin x/x$ as $x \to 0$. Then, we cannot take a substitution which is $0$ in a certain nbhd of $0$, otherwise we'd get an indeterminate form. So, we should avoid this somehow in general.

Comment: Thank you for the follow up. I now understand the theorem and have proven it for myself...but I am having some difficulties applying it to my particular case. About midway through your answer, you claim that my situation can be viewed as: "...In your example, $\varphi(t) = ct$ works since if $$\lim\limits_{h \to h_0} f(h) = \ell$$ exists"...however, I'm not quite certain I see the analogy. Sure, $h_0=0$ in my case...but my function is $\lim_{h \to 0} f(ch)$, *not* $\lim_{h \to 0} f(h)$. If I compose your $\varphi$ function with $f$...is it as simple as $\lim_{t \to 0}f\left(c\varphi(t)\right)$

Comment: (i.e. $c$ just comes along for the ride). I have proven the above statement so I guess it is correct?

Comment: @S.Cramer Yes, and I also appended more thoughts focused on that equivalency.

Comment: Thank you for all of the extra follow up. Cheers~